# How to hide view's shadow after its presenting?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

I want to call a UIView with transparent background from table cell.

```
let myView = MyViewController()
myView.view.backgroundColor = .clear
tableController.present(myView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But there remains such an unpleasant border.
[image]

`myView.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` makes it worse - remove background view.

Comment: How about `myView.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can present new viewController in a .fullscreen (or any other) mode with transparent background

1. Add view with content inside viewController
2. Add custom background color to the main viewController's view. Set `opacity` to any value less than 100% (e.g. 30% - see screen below)
3. Change viewController's presentation style to `.overCurrentContext`

Here is how you can do that programmatically

```
//apply that for viewController that will be displayed at the top
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Important to note, if you're using a .xib, `viewDidLoad` isn't the correct place to place your `modalPresentationStyle` change. This should be done before the view is loaded.